# plan 9 fonts on linux console

Tags: fonts, console, historical-unix, bell

I am wondering how I can convert plan 9 fonts for use with the linux console, there is very little info on the topic. All i can find is vga medium having been ported to true type, but it doesnt look anything like vga medium and sort of sucks.

I will be posting any helpful data I have shortly.

edit:
http://sciops.net/downloads/vga/
the plan 9 vga font can be downloaded for 9front here.

Comment: Weren't all plan9 fonts variable-width? I clearly remember that being a strong esthetical and technical point made by the designers of plan9. The interface to their command windows ("xterms" LOL) in the rio window manager was very deliberately rejecting any column alignment and any curses-like interface.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't clear, you won't have any luck using variable-width fonts in the Linux console.